# How to use PySpark.Pandas assign function?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a function that needs to be run for each row. Basically, the function will take the values from three columns and based on their values it will return one thing or another.

However, I am getting a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` error. I think I am missing how `pyspark.pandas` is working under-the-hood (at row levels), as a very similar code worked fine in `pandas` and the error seems to be related to referencing a list of values, instead of a single value.

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

def clean_input_dataframe(dff_in):
    dff = dff_in.copy()

    dff['ChargeableWeight'] = ps.to_numeric(dff['ChargeableWeight'], errors='coerce')
    dff['ActualWeight'] = ps.to_numeric(dff['ActualWeight'], errors='coerce')
    dff['ActualVolume'] = ps.to_numeric(dff['ActualVolume'], errors='coerce')

    ## LOGIC FOR CORRECTING "ChargeableWeight"
    def correct_chargeableweight(row) -> ps.Series[float]:
        
        chargeableweight = row['ChargeableWeight']
        actualweight = row['ActualWeight']
        actualvolume = row['ActualVolume']

        if chargeableweight <= 0:
            if actualvolume * 166.67 > actualweight:
                return 'a1'#actualvolume * 166.67
            else:
                return 'a2'#actualweight       
        else:
            return 'a3'#chargeableweight


    dff = dff.assign(ChargeableWeight1 = lambda x: correct_chargeableweight(x))

    return dff

dff_in = ps.DataFrame([
    {'ChargeableWeight': 6296.03, 'ActualWeight': None, 'ActualVolume': None},
    {'ChargeableWeight': 9528.16, 'ActualWeight': None, 'ActualVolume': None},
    {'ChargeableWeight': 4080.0, 'ActualWeight': 4044.000, 'ActualVolume': 35.868},
    {'ChargeableWeight': 4080.0, 'ActualWeight': 4044.000, 'ActualVolume': 35.868},
    {'ChargeableWeight': 6.79   , 'ActualWeight': None, 'ActualVolume': None}
])

clean_input_dataframe(dff_in)['ChargeableWeight1']
```